# Confusion on Authors use of the word into as opposed to onto

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

[image]

The function G, which is a mapping of B -> A by the definition in the screenshot should be a mapping from B onto A because all members of B would always mapped to A Right?

Comment: The phrase, let $f$ be a mapping of $X$ into $Y$ means $f: X \to Y$ is a function, one should not attach any meaning other than this to it. Confusingly, I have seen some people use the phrase an "into" function to mean injective, but this is generally not the case, and you should assume the first meaning.

Comment: Please do not use images. Instead typeset the content out, since that makes your post more searchable and accessible. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I think $G$ is onto $A\,.$ It might just be a typo.